# SVG filters on HTML in webkit?

Tags: html, webkit, svg

So I've been messing around with SVG filters, and I'd like to apply them to HTML content.

http://paulirish.com/work/videooo.xhtml - works in firefox, not chrome.
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4031469/woohtml.html - My example, works in FF, not Chrome.

Around the web, I've seen things mentioning the url() syntax for defining svg-based filters, while custom() refers to css shaders.

However, I haven't been able to get the filter working by either using the `filter:` property, nor the `-webkit-filter:` property.

Any ideas on how to get them to work? `about:flags` in Chrome doesn't have any options, so I'm trying to figure out if they're not implemented yet, or if I'm doing something incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the shorthand filters (blur, sepia, etc), Chrome now supports SVG filters on HTML content, as of V.21, using the -webkit-filter: url(#foo) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Webkit doesn't support svg filters on html elements. It does, however, support css filters.

So if you want to support both browsers you could write...

```
selector {
  filter: url(#reference_to_blur);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

You can see more CSS filters here: http://davidwalsh.name/css-filters

I haven't tested, but I doubt IE9 and Opera support css or svg filters in their current incarnations (IE9 and Opera 11).

Comment: Where can I find information about this URL property ? the link you have doesn't tell about the URL property./

Comment: @RoyiNamir take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content